# How to fetch updated state in Component while using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to redux, I am getting confused about how to get State from Redux Store when we have multiple Reducer. 
let Say this is my combineReducer

```
import apiCallInProgress from './ApiStattusReducer'; 
import login from './loginReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login,
    apiCallInProgress
});

export default rootReducer;

// below is my Login Reducer
const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {}

};
export function loginReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    console.log(action.user);
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.SET_CURRENT_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.user
            }
        default:
            return state
    }

}
export default loginReducer;

// now I want to access  user from my component,
// I wrote as  
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        login: state.login
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    const { login } = this.props
    console.log("set user didmount:" + login.user)
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { login } = this.props
    console.log("set user didupdate:" + login.user)

}
```

I am not able to get the state of user in the component but when I am pressing login button console.log(action.user) showing proper output in console .
The variable names we mentioned inside combineReducer, the same name do I need to use inside mapStateToProps func to fetch the state. I am very much confused. Someone, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing everything right till you get to the component (although difficult to fully determine without actually testing the code). The main issue is, as far as I can see, you're not actually dispatching the action so `login.user` is never being set.

The [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/7.1/api/connect#connect) method of react-redux has two function parameters - `mapStateToProps`, which you're using correctly, and `mapDispatchToProps`, which it doesn't look like you're using.

`mapDispatchToProps` is a method to pass Redux actions into props, which when invoked, will fire the action, which will in turn be picked up by the reducer, which will return a new state object. Create a new directory called `actions` in the root of your app. Inside it, create a file called `loginActions.js`, and within that, put something like the following:

```
export function setCurrentUser(user) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_CURRENT_USER', user)
  }
}
```

import this function into your component, then in your connect function, add `mapDispatchToProps`

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setCurrentUser } from './actions/loginActions'

// component code 

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setCurrentUser: setCurrentUser
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        login: state.login
    }
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponentName)
```

In your `componentDidMount` method, you can now call this action:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.setCurrentUser('myUser')
}
```

in `componentDidUpdate`, the user should now be available:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.login !== this.props.login) {
    console.log(this.props.login)
  }
}
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion @TomOakley. It solved my error.

Comment: Hi @CodeGeek, glad it helped. Could you please accept the answer as correct, so that other users visiting this question know it worked for you? To do this hover under the Upvote/Down vote arrows (top of the question on the left) and a tick should appear. Click that tick and it'll go green. For more info [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks.